# Index out of range error when using for x in y Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

My code is as follows, and using the for x in y structure to iterate through an array.

```
with open('userIDs.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file_IDs:
    csv_reader_IDs = csv.reader(csv_file_IDs, delimiter=',')
    for rowID in csv_reader_IDs:
        data = [rowID[0], rowID[1], rowID[2], rowID[3], rowID[4]]
        userIDs.append(data)
```

However, I'm getting the following error when trying to run my code.

```
in <module>
    data = [rowID[0], rowID[1], rowID[2], rowID[3], rowID[4]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've checked that there are no blank lines in the CSV file, and that each row contains five columns. An example of the CSV file is as follows.

```
123,TESTS,Bloggs,Joe,TESTB
```

Comment: And did you check if there are at least 5 columns in every row in the input file?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could share an example of your userIDs.csv file!

Comment: @blhsing Yes I did, I've tried to simplify it to just one row which has five columns and I'm still getting the same error. I've included a screenshot above.

Comment: @AnweshCR7 I've simplified it to just one row and included an example of the file now!

Comment: Are you sure that the userIDs.csv file is in the same directory as your Python script?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that at least one of the lines in your CSV file does not contain the requisite number of values.

It would be simpler to do this:

```
import csv
with open('userIDs.csv') as csv_file_IDs:
    userIDs = [e[:5] for e in csv.reader(csv_file_IDs)]
    print(userIDs)
```

You could then examine the list (*userIDs*) for any elements that don't have enough values

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't the issue. I tried reducing the CSV file to only have one row which definitely has five columns, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @JannikW Please add a fragment of the CSV content to the question

Comment: There is a fragment in the question, I've changed it from a link to being in the body. Even with this as the only line in the CSV, I get the same error.

Comment: @JannikW I have created a file with **exactly** the text that you've added to the question. The output from the code in this answer is *[['123', 'TESTS', 'Bloggs', 'Joe', 'TESTB']]* With blank lines both before and after the significant text the output is *[[], ['123', 'TESTS', 'Bloggs', 'Joe', 'TESTB'], []]* as expected